# PHP: Как с помощью XPath получить содержимое ряда тегов в дерево DOM, сохранив их порядок в html?

Tags: php, парсер, объекты, dom, xpath

Пытаюсь заполнить спаршенными данными таблицы, но не получается разобрать html. Не понимаю, как получить общий DOM тегов родителей и нескольких тегов детей так, чтобы дети сохранили связь с родителями. Например, если дата внтури одного дива, а нужная ссылка - внутри другого, год в еще одном диве, общим для группы дивов, то мне надо сохранить привязку лет, дат, ссылок.

Исходный html имеет такую структуру:

```
<div class='history'>
<div>..</div>
<a class='history-item'></a>
</div>
```

Я делаю такую штуку:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);

//echo $html;

$document = new DOMDocument();

$document->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$elements = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"history")]');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($elements['elements']);
echo '<pre>';
```

В итоге, я получаю содержимое общего класса versions, но из этого DOM, я не могу взять ссылку  (более вложенного узла почему-то нет), а ведь мне нужен и родитель и несколько детей...

Может быть, кто-нибудь из более опытных коллег подскажет, что можно сделать? Собственные поиски ни к чему не привели..

Comment: для парсинга и работы с html все же больше используют какой-нить  SimpleHTMLDom а не инструменты для xml

Comment: Хотелось бы встроенным в php инструментом.. А SimpleHTMLDom, насколько я понял, библиотека, которая нуждается в установке и подключении..

Comment: тогда найдите все ссылки по классу и верните родительский узел.

Comment: А как это сделать? Перерыл море статей ничего в этом роде не видел..

Comment: `..` обращаются к родителю, как ни странно